# How do I pass integers into an instance where the parameter type is an integer array rather than an integer

Tags: java, arrays, oop

FIRST CLASS

```
public class Student {
public String name;
public int IDnumber;
public int[] marks;

// constructor
public Student(String name, int IDnumber, int[] marks){
    this.name = name;
    this.IDnumber = IDnumber;
    this.marks = marks;
}}
```

SECOND SEPARATE CLASS

```
public class StudentCreator {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Student alex = new Student("Alex", 12, 78);
    System.out.println(javonne.marks);
}}
```

Sorry if im getting confused with the jargon, im still new. In the second separate class im trying to add some integers into my instance but im not sure how since the parameters type for marks is an integer array rather than an integer. The instance alex should have 78 stored in his array under marks

Comment: Duplicates: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29109147/how-to-pass-int-array-as-an-argument-to-a-constructor or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11698283/passing-a-string-array-as-a-parameter-to-a-function-java

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the student only has one mark then just create a new array like so

```
Student alex = new Student("Alex", 12, new int[]{78});
```

Or you could maybe make your code more flexible by allowing marks to be passed in as var args.

```
public Student(String name, int IDnumber, int... marks){
...
}
```

Then your original student instantiation could stay as is.

Also just printing `student.marks` is going to just give you the reference to the object hash. Try something like `Arrays.toString(student.marks)`.

Comment: Thank you the vararg solution is perfect. But lets say i add 3 int's in the marks parameter, how would i print all of the entries in the array? Would i have to do it manually indexing with square brackets 3 times?

Comment: Nope, you could just use `Arrays.toString(student.marks)`.

Answer (score 1):

To create a new int array in java, you use the syntax

`int[] myArray = new int[size];`

To create an already initialized array, the syntax is

`int[] myArray = new int[]{1,2,3,4,5};`

Of note, myArray is a reference to the int array.  So, if you modify the contents of the array, it will be reflected everywhere that shares a reference to that array.

Also, a "javaism", `int[]` and `Integer[]` are two different array types.  `Integer[]` is an array of Integer objects. `int[]` is an array of primitive integer values.  In practice, what this means is that `int[]` can't contain `null`s and `Integer[]` can.  It also means you can't call methods taking `int[]` with `Integer[]` and vice versa.